# Using pandas to write df to sqlite

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I'm trying to create a sqlite db from a csv file. After some searching it seems like this is possible using a pandas df. I've tried following some tutorials and the documentation but I can't figure this error out. Here's my code:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas, csv, sqlite3

# Create sqlite database and cursor
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
# Create the table of pitches
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pitches (
            pitch_type text,
            game_date text,
            release_speed real
            )""")

conn.commit()

df = pandas.read_csv('test2.csv')
df.to_sql('pitches', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)

conn.close()
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: table pitches has no column named SL
```

SL is the first value in the first row in my csv file. I can't figure out why it's looking at the csv value as a column name, unless it thinks the first row of the csv should be the headers and is trying to match that to column names in the table? I don't think that was it either though because I tried changing the first value to an actual column name and got the same error.

EDIT:

When I have the headers in the csv, the dataframe looks like this:

```
     pitch_type  game_date  release_speed
0            SL  8/31/2017           81.9
1            SL  8/31/2017           84.1
2            SL  8/31/2017           81.9
...         ...        ...            ...
2919         SL   8/1/2017           82.3
2920         CU   8/1/2017           78.7

[2921 rows x 3 columns]
```

and I get the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: table pitches has no column named game_date
```

When I take the headers out of the csv file:

```
      SL  8/31/2017  81.9
0     SL  8/31/2017  84.1
1     SL  8/31/2017  81.9
2     SL  8/31/2017  84.1
...   ..        ...   ...
2918  SL   8/1/2017  82.3
2919  CU   8/1/2017  78.7

[2920 rows x 3 columns]
```

and I get the following error:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: table pitches has no column named SL
```

EDIT #2:

I tried taking the table creation out of the code entirely, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900593/csv-into-sqlite-table-python), with the following code:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas, csv, sqlite3

# Create sqlite database and cursor
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

df = pandas.read_csv('test2.csv')
df.to_sql('pitches', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)

conn.close()
```

and still get the

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: table pitches has no column named SL
```

error

EDIT #3:

I changed the table creation code to the following:

```
# Create the table of pitches
dropTable = 'DROP TABLE pitches'
c.execute(dropTable)
createTable = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pitches(pitch_type text, game_date text, release_speed real)"
c.execute(createTable)
```

and it works now. Not sure what exactly changed, as it looks basically the same to me, but it works.

Comment: Can you post how your dataframe looks like? You definitely should get a different error once you assigned column names in your csv file.

Comment: Edited with the requested information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your column names. I am able to replicate your code successfully with no errors. The `names` variable gets all the columns names from the `sqlite` table and you can compare them with the dataframe headers with `df.columns`.

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd, csv, sqlite3

# Create sqlite database and cursor
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
# Create the table of pitches
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS pitches (
            pitch_type text,
            game_date text,
            release_speed real
            )""")
conn.commit()

test = conn.execute('SELECT * from pitches')
names = [description[0] for description in test.description]
print(names)

df = pd.DataFrame([['SL','8/31/2017','81.9']],columns = ['pitch_type','game_date','release_speed'])
df.to_sql('pitches', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)

conn.execute('SELECT * from pitches').fetchall()
>> [('SL', '8/31/2017', 81.9), ('SL', '8/31/2017', 81.9)]
```

I am guessing there might be some whitespaces in your column headers.

Comment: It's also strange to me that the error says "no column named game_date" when that's the second column in the table. I can't figure out why it would skip over the pitch_type column, or decide that it was okay.

Comment: Using your answer I found that when I print(names) in line 17 of your code it only shows ['pitch_type'], so there must be something wrong with my syntax of creating the table. I can't figure out what though.

Comment: Are your other columns numbered? You need to assign column headers for all of them. `to_sql` assigns the column values based on your column names in your dataframe in this case.

Comment: I changed the table creation code (added it to Edit #3 in the original post), and it works now. Not sure what was wrong in the initial code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: i got similar error message with sqlite3 while using `df.to_sql('table_name',engine,index=False, if_exists='append')`, it turned out in my case that my pandas dataframe df had some **multi-level indexes**. After having dropped them, it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to create a table from a csv file you can just run sqlite3 and do:

```
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import c:/path/to/file/myfile.csv myTableName
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from pandas [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) docs:

```
header : int or list of ints, default 'infer'
    Row number(s) to use as the column names, and the start of the
    data.  Default behavior is to infer the column names: if no names
    are passed the behavior is identical to ``header=0`` and column
    names are inferred from the first line of the file, if column
    names are passed explicitly then the behavior is identical to
    ``header=None``. Explicitly pass ``header=0`` to be able to
    replace existing names. The header can be a list of integers that
    specify row locations for a multi-index on the columns
    e.g. [0,1,3]. Intervening rows that are not specified will be
    skipped (e.g. 2 in this example is skipped). Note that this
    parameter ignores commented lines and empty lines if
    ``skip_blank_lines=True``, so header=0 denotes the first line of
    data rather than the first line of the file.
```

That means read_csv using your first row as header names.